# TypeScript cyclic/recursive interface definition

Tags: typescript, types, typeorm

## Base case

I'm having trouble defining a modular type system that suits my needs in a modular way. Here's a simple version of my problem :

I need two slightly different representations of pretty much the same types system : One for the frontend, one for the backend (I'll explain the difference later, now this is only for context). I'm trying to define a types system where I'm able to derive one from the other, as it seems theorically doable.

Here's how to understand the model :

- A `User` has multiple `Team`s.
- A `Team` has multiple `Unit`s.

That's all there is conceptually : (A)

```js
type IUser = {
    username: string,
    teams: ITeam[],
};

type ITeam = {
    teamname: string,
    user: IUser ,
    units: IUnit[],
}

type IUnit = {
    unitname: string,
    team: ITeam ,
}
```

I need to be able to access each relation in both ways (both `User -> Team`, and `Team -> User` for example). From the User down to the Unit, and from the Unit up to the User.

## Context

That works well to type what my frontend will play with. Now, here's what I need to represent in the backend : I'm using TypeORM, so each of these is an Entity and reality the code rather looks like this :

(B) (*this is also mostly for context, there's a playground stripped of any TypeORM logic lower)*

```js
import {Entity, Column, OneToMany, ManyToOne} from "typeorm";

@Entity()
class User extends BaseEntity {
    @Column()
    username: string,

    // A User has many Teams, loaded lazily
    @OneToMany(() => Team, (team) => team.user, {})
    teams: Promise<Team[]>,
};

@Entity()
class Team extends BaseEntity {
    @Column()
    teamname: string,

    // A Team is owned by one User, loaded eagerly
    @ManyToOne(() => User, (user) => user.teams, {
        eager: true,
    })
    user: User,

    // A Team has many Units, loaded lazily
    @OneToMany(() => Unit, (unit) => unit.team, {})
    units: Promise<Unit[]>,
}

@Entity()
class Unit extends BaseEntity {
    @Column()
    unitname: string,

    // A Unit is owned by one Team, loaded eagerly
    @ManyToOne(() => Team, (team) => team.units, {
        eager: true,
    })
    team: Team,
}
```

Now of course as [the documentation of TypeORM](https://typeorm.io/#/eager-and-lazy-relations/eager-relations) tells us :

> Eager relations can only be used on one side of the relationship, using eager: true on both sides of relationship is disallowed.

So I chose a direction in which all relations would load eagerly, and an other where they'd load lazily. I decided I'd load the descending way lazily (cause in my use case I won't need every Team of a User every time), and load the ascending way eagerly (cause I'll want to know the User of a Unit every time in my use case).

## What I want

I want to verify that model (B) is just model (A) with some promisified fields.

---

## Problem

Now I can't verify that model (B) has anything to do with model (A), because some of the properties the fields reference also have been promisified.

---

## What I tried

You can follow along this TypeScript playground link, which strips this problems of the TypeORM context and focuses on the actual type definitions : [Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-jwqEoBjP+Hqaq2wFMCeJByA0w7uhamoAGLETCDA0fA-oPPAAAefCoKeoCwbanhgdoIYQhgdGgAxTFgQAZORAHyEBIGQMgxzCaJp7woi2FgLhlFbjsAAGykkDp1q2r+oA6Z4OmzqAC5SoqyigDWVrxjG36kZEAAiZwAPpPC0mmbvpUJqBoDApjEJBJoi9TuV5TyeYCDzaB53kaL4oVuEm-ghOpoBQgAtPe1BqqwSWxfFSpmnY+EcDqzTsHcezwOQoDrnhXqCJ8lnipK8iRqAZjdqAdVqtYjVWhwsYRhCmRSKAYb2ZGX7wAw40PDYyCEfGyw2am6aZhGqA5u8VglQWUrwMWTxlmEt5VjWdbQLgWD9XwuDyMt7CxrG0qStubBkTKT4IKAuDUNQRzzMwrA-mRoOEAloAnXkqXxRlFZgJ4H0PLGg4mZp8CBYCCIoAdrgDraeMwjECKWXeioYMqJDULgw0raAAZAA)

I've put the two models I described earlier, as well as my current reasoning on how I could use one to derive from the other. But now I'm stuck : You can read until the end of the playground to understand that I'd need some kind of recursion that I don't know how to express.

Answer (score 2):

My approach for fixing this is to make sure that the frontend and backend versions both implement some shared interface.  For this shared interface, I say that a value can either be a promise or a resolved value by creating a utility type `MaybePromise<T>`:

```
type MaybePromise<T> = T | Promise<T>;
```

Using this utility type, I redefine the `I` interfaces to be the shared base, which might or might not have promises.

```
type IUser = {
    username: string,
    teams: MaybePromise<ITeam[]>,
};

type ITeam = {
    teamname: string,
    user: MaybePromise<IUser>,
    units: MaybePromise<IUnit[]>,
}

type IUnit = {
    unitname: string,
    team: MaybePromise<ITeam>,
}
```

If we want to get back the original non-promised interfaces, we can do that using another utility type which will replace these maybe promises with their resolved values.

```
type UnpromisifyFields<T> = {
    [key in keyof T]: T[key] extends MaybePromise<infer U> ? UnpromisifyFields<U> : T[key]
}
```

Making this recursive means that the resolved types aren't particularly readable, but they do seem to be correct.

```
type PureUser = UnpromisifyFields<IUser>
// becomes { username: string; teams: UnpromisifyFields<ITeam>[]; }

type PureTeam = UnpromisifyFields<ITeam>

type PureUnit = UnpromisifyFields<IUnit>
```

Our backend classes are able to implement the base `MaybePromise` interfaces:

```
class User implements IUser {    
    username!: string;
    teams!: Promise<Team[]>;
};

class Team implements ITeam {
    teamname!: string;
    user!: User;
    units!: Promise<Unit[]>;
}

class Unit implements IUnit {
    unitname!: string;
    team!: Team;
}
```

I think this solves most of your issues.

Comment: Oh, right. I actually did have this at some point, and I thought that I could do better but I think it's been over-engineering at that point. Thanks